# fancybox stripping away the <form> tag

Tags: asp.net, fancybox

I'm using FancyBox jquery plugin to display modal popup boxes.

The site is: http://www.chatisfying.com

To see a sample of the fancybox dialog in question please go here: http://www.chatisfying.com/Mohali/

If you check, the `<div id="getPassCode"></div>` should have a `<form>` as its only child element.

I'm using a web user control, to generate the modal box content, here is the code:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ucGetPassCode.ascx.cs" Inherits="UserControls_Default_ucGetPassCode" %>

<div style="display:none;">
<div id="getPassCode">
  <form action="<%= Request.RawUrl %>" id="passcode">


  <div class="Block">
    <div class="label"><%= ms.GetValue("pass_code_label",3)%></div>
    <div class="float_left">


                <input type="text" name="TextBox_PassCode" runat="server" title="" id="TextBox_PassCode" value="" />
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
        ControlToValidate="TextBox_PassCode" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="*"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>



    <% 
        if (this.qaTable != null && this.qaTable.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (FlexChatUpdate2.ThemeQuestionAnswersRow r in this.qaTable)
            {
    %>
            <div class="Block">
                <div class="label"><%= ms.GetValue("question_label",3)%></div>
                <div class="float_left">
                    <%= r.ThemeQuestion %>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="Block">
                <div class="label"><%= ms.GetValue("answer_label",3)%></div>
                <div class="float_left">
                    <input type="text" name="answers" value="" />
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
    <%
            }
        }
    %>

    <div class="Block">
    <div class="label">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="float_left">
      <input id="Button_GetTheme" name="Button_GetTheme" type="submit" value="" runat="server" />

    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="Block">
    <div class="label">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="float_left">


      <a href="<%= ResolveUrl("../../RequestPassCode.aspx?ThemeID=" + this.ThemeID.ToString()) %>"><%= ms.GetValue("request_passcode_link_text",3)%></a> |
            <a href="<%= this._root %>"><%= ms.GetValue("back_home_link_text",3)%></a>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
    </form>
</div>
</div>

<a style="display:none;" href="#getPassCode" class="getpasscode_trigger">get pass code</a>
```

I have used jqModal before fancybox, and it had the form tag without problem. Can anyone help me, where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i resolved this by wrapping the #getPassCode with a  tag, after fancy box content display is complete. like this -

```
onComplete: function()
{
  $('#getPassCode').wrap('<form action="<%= Request.RawUrl %>" method="post" />');
},
```

This reinserted the  tag that was stripped away. May be a messy workaround, but it works :D

Answer (score 1):

You should check that form tag is not inside another form tag.